# How to tell SilverStripe that a folder of code (containing a _config subfolder) is not a SilverStripe module?

Tags: module, silverstripe

I have a non-SilverStripe app I want to store in a folder in the root of my SilverStripe website folder. Let's call it myApp.

It has a folder in it called _config (ie myApp/_config)

When I do a flush of the site, I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'There are two files containing the "Event" class: ...
```

Apparently SilverStripe is trying to treat myApp as a module, thanks to the existence of the _config folder (this is [documented here](http://docs.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/extending/modules/)). How can I tell it not to do that?

Answer (score 2):

In file *core/manifest/ManifestFileFinder.php* I found something that seemed to cause modules to be excluded. It turns out I needed to add a file to the *myApp* folder named *_manifest_exclude*

Once that file existed, it fixed the problem.